# How to query DATETIME field using only date in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table TEST with a `DATETIME` field, like this:

```
ID NAME DATE
1 TESTING 2014-03-19 20:05:20.000
```

What I need a query returning this row and every row with date 03/19/2014, no matter what the time is. I tried using

```sql
select * from test where date = '03/19/2014';
```

But it returns no rows. The only way to make it work that I found is to also provide the time portion of the date:

```sql
select * from test where date = '03/19/2014 20:03:02.000';
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

use range, or  DateDiff function

```
 select * from test 
 where date >= '20140319' and date < '20140320'
```

or

```
 select * from test 
 where datediff(day, date, '03/19/2014') = 0
```

Other options are:

1. If you have control over the database schema, and you don't need the
   time data, take it out.
2. or, if you must keep it, add a computed column attribute that has the time portion of the date value stripped off...

`Alter table Test  Add DateOnly As  DateAdd(day, datediff(day, 0, date), 0)`

or, in more recent versions of SQL Server...

`Alter table Test  Add DateOnly As  Cast(DateAdd(day, datediff(day, 0, date), 0) as Date)`

then, you can write your query as simply:

```
select * from test 
where DateOnly = '03/19/2014'
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but i was wondering if is there any easier way.

Comment: Well, the only other easier way is not to put time data into the database in the first place... or create a computed attribute that strips off the time portion and use it... I added both options to my answer.

Comment: I was concerned that the DATEDIFF method would return true (undesirably) for dates like 4/19/2014 or 3/19/2015, as the 'day' portion of those dates is the same (and I had seen reports elsewhere that it would act in this way), but I tested it against a database, and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: Yes, because the `DateDiff()` function, in all its variants, computes and returns the number of date *boundaries* that must be crossed to get frlom one date to the other.  This is why `DateDiff(day, '1Jan2016', '31Dec2017 23:259:59')` and `DateDiff(day, '31Dec2016 23:259:59', '1Jan2017 ')`  both return `1`.

Comment: Not all days have 24 hours. This will fail on those particular dates.

Comment: @Linus, No it won't, because the number of hours in the day is irrelevant. The function does not count hours, it counts date boundaries.

Answer (score 73):

Simple answer;

```
select * from test where cast ([date] as date) = '03/19/2014';
```

Comment: While this is a valid answer I want to point putting the date field evaluating behind any function will lead to performance problems. Any index on the date will be useless and the engine will need to evaluate each row

Answer (score 28):

I am using MySQL 5.6 and there is a DATE function to extract only the date part from date time. So the simple solution to the question is -

```
 select * from test where DATE(date) = '2014-03-19';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: question is about sql server

Comment: this solved it for me; despite the question referencing sql server, Google redirects to here as the top result for "SQL" in general; so many users that land here may not be using MSS specifically.

Answer (score 12):

This works for me for MS SQL server:

```
select * from test
where 
year(date) = 2015
and month(date) = 10
and day(date)= 28 ;
```

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from test 
where date between '03/19/2014' and '03/19/2014 23:59:59'
```

This is a realy **bad** answer. For two reasons.

1.
What happens with times like 23.59.59.700 etc.
There are times larger than 23:59:59 and the next day.

2.
The behaviour depends on the datatype.
The query behaves differently for datetime/date/datetime2 types.

Testing with 23:59:59.999 makes it even worse because depending on the datetype you get different roundings.

```
select convert (varchar(40),convert(date      , '2014-03-19 23:59:59.999'))
select convert (varchar(40),convert(datetime  , '2014-03-19 23:59:59.999'))
select convert (varchar(40),convert(datetime2 , '2014-03-19 23:59:59.999'))
```

-- For date the value is 'chopped'.
-- For datetime the value is rounded up to the next date. (Nearest value).
-- For datetime2 the value is precise.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
select * from TableName where DateTimeField > date() and  DateTimeField < date() + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select * from test where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date)) = '03/19/2014';
```

Comment: Thank you, but i think the simpler solution would be a comparison with time, just like the previous solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with dates and languages and the way to avoid it is asking for dates with this format YYYYMMDD.

This way below should be the fastest according to the link below. I checked in SQL Server 2012 and I agree with the link.

```
select * from test where date >= '20141903' AND date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '20141903');
```

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select * from test where Convert(varchar, date,111)= '03/19/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach which truncates the time part:

```
select * from test
where convert(datetime,'03/19/2014',102) = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Reverse the date format
-- this false:
    select * from test where date = '28/10/2015'
-- this true:
    select * from test where date = '2015/10/28'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: This doesn't work because '2015/10/28 00:00.001' is different from '2015/10/28'

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this in your `WHERE` clause.

The "SubmitDate" portion below is the column name, so insert your own.

This will return only the "Year" portion of the results, omitting the mins etc.

```
Where datepart(year, SubmitDate) = '2017'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *, cast ([col1] as date) <name of the column> from test where date = 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

"col1" is name of the column with date and time
<name of the column> here you can change name as desired

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
  from invoice
 where TRUNC(created_date) <=TRUNC(to_date('04-MAR-18 15:00:00','dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Answer (score -2):

Test this query.

```
SELECT *,DATE(chat_reg_date) AS is_date,TIME(chat_reg_time) AS is_time FROM chat WHERE chat_inbox_key='$chat_key' 
                         ORDER BY is_date DESC, is_time DESC
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from invoice where TRANS_DATE_D>= to_date  ('20170831115959','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
and TRANS_DATE_D<= to_date  ('20171031115959','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

Comment: I think this is Oracle syntax, do not work at sql server

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT * FROM test where DATEPART(year,[TIMESTAMP]) = '2018'  and  DATEPART(day,[TIMESTAMP]) = '16' and  DATEPART(month,[TIMESTAMP]) = '11'
```

Answer (score -4):

use trunc(column).

```
select * from test t where trunc(t.date) = TO_DATE('2018/06/08', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```