# Have issues with DateTime Parameter on SSIS Project

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I having an issue with my date parameter on my SSIS project report. I need to query products registered by date (today's date). Below is a query in which i am passing ...

```
SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE [CreatedDateTime] = @Date
```

In the @Date parameter, I have specified the value to be today's date so in the default value section I have passed this expression '=Today()' which gets the actual days date.

Now the issue i'm having here is that when i run this report it does not return any results even thought the results are in the database. Its after running a few tests when i realised that the way the dateTime is stored in my database is different from way my `@Date` parameter is being executed. for example:

in my View on Sql server I have a CreatedDateTime column storing the date in this format: `2016-04-14 08:58:07.140` < stores date and time as you can see.

on SSIS my @Date is only filtering by date , so for instance it will only query by 2016-04-14 (by date only  not time) and hence no results are being returned.

I discovered this by adding a textbox to filter by entered date .. when i enter the date only , no results are returned but when i enter the date together with time , the results are returned.

Is there a method i cuould pass in my @Date parameter other than the =Today() which will will work in my case and only filter by date?

Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this with the help of :
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506930/how-to-query-datetime-field-using-only-date-in-sql-server)

So I changed my sql statement like so :

```
SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE CAST([CreatedDateTime] AS DATE) = @Date
```

and it worked!

Comment: That's because you had a SQL issue, not an SSIS issue. You were comparing a date-only value with a value that also contained time. They would match only if the time portion was `00:00`