# Get data between two times for the last 30 days

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to pull data from the last 30 days and I am using this function

```
DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

I am getting the data but it looks like it is missing some Like when I look at the data for specific date it doesn't include all the 24 hours data I am missing some. I need the data to include the 24 hours data for every day for the last 30 days.

```
select 
    *
from 
    Travel R
where 
    R.s9_date > CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())) 
order by 
    R.s9_date
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query DATETIME field using only date in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506930/how-to-query-datetime-field-using-only-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

GETDATE() returns a datetime which includes the hours, minutes, seconds, etc. Therefore when you subtract 30 days from that, the subtracted value will also have the time part.

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2008 or above, you can convert the datetime to a date by wrapping the DATEADD function with a CONVERT function:

```
CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thank you Rick, I tried your suggestion but it is still missing data. what if I want it to show the data from 5:00 am to 5:00 am for every day for the last 30 days?

Comment: You should post your query in the original question.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that s9_date is only storing a date. In that case you would need to use >= instead of >

Comment: the s9_date column is a datetime type.  I tried >= but that didn't work too.

Comment: can I do something like this? (DateAdd("d",-30,Today) & " 03:00:00 AM") select the data between two dates fro the last 30 days? I know that this is not the right formula but I was wondering if there is something like this? I am fairly new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `CAST` was introduced in SQL Server 2005

```
select
    *
from
    Travel R
where
    R.s9_date > CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
order by
    R.s9_date
```