# SQL query for specific time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm totally new to SQL and want to run a query where I want to get revenue **from Sep-16 to Mar-17**. I'm trying to write a query like this:

```
SELECT revenue 
  FROM myapp_financialdata
 WHERE financial_year  = 2016 
   AND financial_month = 9
   AND financial_year  = 2017
   AND financial_month = 3
```

I know I'm totally doing it wrong. Can anyone please help me for some query which I can use dynamically not only for above period but also for something like **from Jan-17 to Jun-17**?

**UPDATE:**

Here is screenshot of table:

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506930/how-to-query-datetime-field-using-only-date-in-sql-server

Comment: I believe PostgreSQL supports the `between` clause. Basically your `where` clause can be `where financial year between '2017-09-01' and '2017-03-31'` etc

Comment: It's a bit unusual to store the month and year separately, which will make the query more complicated. Can you show us what the table looks like?

Comment: I've updated the question with screen shot of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, the usual answer is to use the `BETWEEN` operator -- postgresql's support for dates and times is pretty thorough, and that will work for most situations.

That query would look something like:

```
SELECT revenue FROM myapp_financialdata
  WHERE financialdate BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2017-03-01';
```

And would return all of the rows which match those dates. If you'd rather get a single number (say, the sum total revenue), then you would use `SELECT sum(revenue) FROM ...`.

But if your table does keep the year and month in separate columns, it's more complicated.

If both dates are in the same year, it's fairly straightforward:

```
SELECT sum(revenue) FROM myapp_financialdata
  WHERE
    financial_year = 2017
    AND (financial_month BETWEEN 1 AND 6);
```

That gives you everything from January to June of 2017.

If the period spans two years, it looks like:

```
SELECT sum(revenue) from myapp_financialdata
  WHERE
    (financial_year = 2016 AND
     financial_month >= 9)
    OR
    (financial_year = 2017 AND
     financial_month <= 3);
```

As you can see, that's more complicated than when there's a single `date` column. It gets a little more complicated if you want to span several years:

```
SELECT sum(revenue) from myapp_financialdata
  WHERE
    (financial_year = 2012 AND
     financial_month >= 4)
    OR
    (financial_year BETWEEN 2013 AND 2016)
    OR
    (financial_year = 2017 AND
     financial_month <= 6);
```

That grabs the total revenue between April of 2012 and June of 2017.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your date column is called 'financial_date', here is how your query should be like:

```
SELECT revenue,financial_date  FROM myapp_financialdata
WHERE financial_date between '2016-09-01' and '2017-03-31'
```

(BETWEEN PostgreSQL)Reference: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-between/

Answer (score 2):

If the year and month are separated in two columns you can write:

```
select revenue
  from myapp_financialdata
  where (financial_year = 2016 and financial_month >= 9)
     or (financial_year = 2017 and financial_month <= 3);
```

If the year and month are in a single date column you can write:

```
select revenue
  from myapp_financialdata
  where financial_date between '2016-09-01' and '2017-03-31';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT revenue 
  FROM myapp_financialdata
 WHERE to_date(to_char(financial_year)||to_char(financial_month),'RRRRMM') BETWEEN to_date('2016-09-01','RRRR-MM-DD') AND to_date('2017-03-31','RRRR-MM-DD')
```