# Date difference = 0 in where clause Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506930/how-to-query-datetime-field-using-only-date-in-sql-server). The only difference is that I use Oracle. I want to select the rows which has `insertion_date='20.11.2018'`. So my query was

```
select * from table where insertion_date='20.11.2018'
```

In that question they suggested `datediff`, so I looked at its equivalent in oracle and I learned that I can do date arithmetic. So I tried somethings like these:

```
select * from table where insertion_date -'20.11.2018'=0;
```

It gave `ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected date got number`.

So, then I tried;

```
select * from table where insertion_date - to_date('20.11.2018', 'dd.MM.YYYY') = 0;
```

It does not give error but also does not display the results which I know there must be. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

**Update:** Sorry I forgot to mention that `insertion_date` is type `date`. But it also has time(hour, minutes, seconds) info in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `INSERTION_DATE`'s datatype?

If it is `DATE`, then comparing it to another date (note: this is date literal; value you used is a string!)

```
select * from table where insertion_date = date '2018-11-20'
```

might work, unless `INSERTION_DATE` contains time component (hours and minutes). Then, the simplest option is to truncate its value (so that you get date itself, at midnight):

```
select * from table where trunc(insertion_date) = date '2018-11-20'
```

but it'll *ruin* index you have on that column (unless it is a function-based one). For small tables, it won't make any difference. For large amount of data, it would so convert it to

```
select * from table where insertion_date >= date '2018-11-20'
                      and insertion_date <  date '2018-11-21'
```

If, on the other hand, `INSERTION_DATE` is a string (`VARCHAR2` or `CHAR`) datatype (which is a really bad idea; consider switching to `DATE` datatype), then you have to know its format, convert it to `DATE` first and then compare to another date. For example, if it was a string that contains date values in format `dd.mm.yyyy`, then

```
select * from table where to_date(insertion_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') = date '2018-11-20'
```

This will certainly fail if any string in that column doesn't match such a format or contains invalid values (such as "date" 53.67.Bx48).

Comment: All DATE values contain a time component in Oracle

Comment: I should have said "whose time component is different from 00:00".

Comment: Ok, thanks @Littlefoot. Second solution you provided works for me.

Comment: @csel - As Littlefoot said, the 2nd solution will ` ruin index you have on that column `.  The 3rd solution is the way to go if you don't want to have to ***scan _every_ single row in the table***.

Comment: I have gone with the 3rd solution actually because I have large table. But I did not understand the "will ruin index you have on that column" part. Can you explain or suggest me a link which explains it  @MatBailie ?

Comment: What I understand is if I use trunc it will apply trunc to insertion_date values of all records which is I guess takes time ?

Comment: It would make a difference if there was an index on INSERTION_DATE column. If there's none, nothing much would happen as query will have to scan the whole table anyway. However, if you frequently use that column in your queries, consider indexing it.